# What is the problem with this code to find the count of the digits of the same number that are divisible by the number?

Tags: c, runtime-error, logic

My code gives a runtime error:

```c
int findDigits(int n) {
    int count = 0, num = n, rem;

    while (num != 0) {
        rem = num % 10;

        if (n % rem == 0) {
            count++;
        }

        num = num / 10;
    }
    return count;
}
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the runtime error you get? Please provide code snippets that are complete and compilable.

Comment: For me it is not fully clear what you try to achieve. Please provide sample input and expected output. As well as the incorrect output you get, if any.

Comment: Hint: What is the range of possible values for `rem`? What is result of `n%rem` for the limits of that range?

Comment: Is the run time error is Floating point Exception ?

Comment: The reason is that rem can be zero causing a division by zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you will try to calculated the modulo of 0 for some number.

Let's say you input is 10, then `num` will be 10 for the first iteration and `rem = 0` because `10 % 10 == 0`. Then in the condition for the if statement you will try to calculate `n % rem` which is `10 % 0` which results in an error.

You should simply catch this case in the if statement like

```cs
if (rem != 0 && n % rem == 0)
{
    ...
}
```

This works because if you have an if-statement like `if (A && B) {...}` the expresion for `B` will only be exceuted if the expression for `A` results in `true` (what would be 1 in c). This is because if `A` results in `false` there is no way that the expression `A && B` can be `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
rem=num%10;

if(n%rem==0)
```

Possible results for the remainder are in the range of `0..9`.

If you put a `0` into the expression of the condition, you get a division by zero error.

You first have to check if `rem!=0` before you can to the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing's wrong with your logic except when the digit is 0.

After you extract a digit from your number, `rem = num % 10;`

You should first check if it's 0 before checking if the number is divisible by this digit. Because division by zero is undefined and is the source of your error. So, don't increment the `count` if `rem == 0`.

For example, consider n = 30:

In the first iteration: rem = 30 % 10 = 0 => n % rem => ERROR (attempted 30 / 0)

This could happen at any iteration given that the digit is 0.

**Solution:**

Change

```
if (n % rem == 0) {
    count++;
}
```

to:

```
// making sure that rem is not zero before dividing n by rem
if (rem != 0 && n % rem == 0) {
    count++;
}
```

Aside: It would have been better to name `rem` as `digit`.

Answer (score -4):

This code does not give any errors

```
#include<stdio.h>
int findDigits(int n) {

int count=0,num=n,rem;

while(num!=0)
{

    rem=num%10;
    if(rem!=0){
    if(n%rem==0)
    {

        count++;

    }
    }
    num=num/10;
}
return count;
}
int main()
{
    printf("%d",findDigits(405)); //enter the numbe to find digits that are divisible
    return 0;
}
```